# Conditionally add options to tcolorbox highlight math style

Tags: conditionals, tcolorbox, package-writing, pgfopts

I have defined the following package:

```
% Configuration
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{eqbox}[2018/01/01 Boxed Equations]
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{fancybox}
\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Package options
\pgfkeys{
    /eqbox/.cd,
    colframe/.store in = \colframe,
    colframe = ,
    colback/.store in = \colback,
    colback = white,
    shadow/.store in = \shadow,
    shadow = ,
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/eqbox}

% Main style
\tcbset{
    highlight math style={
        enhanced,
        sharp corners,
        breakable,
        boxrule = 0.4pt,
        boxsep = 3pt,
        left = 0pt,
        right = 0pt,
        top = 0pt,
        bottom = 0pt
    }
}

% Conditional styles
\ifx\colframe\empty\else\tcbset{colframe = \colframe}\fi
\ifx\colback\empty\else\tcbset{colback = \colback}\fi
\ifx\shadow\empty\else\tcbset{shadow = {2pt}{-2pt}{0mm}{\shadow}}\fi
```

The way it works it that, first, a main style is defined. And then, if the user provide their options when loading the package (for example `\usepackage[shadow=blue]{eqbox}`), then options are added.

The problem is that in the current version, the global `tcolorbox` `colframe`, `colback` and `shadow` parameters are changed. Instead of that, I would like to change the `highlight math style` `colframe`, `colback` and `shadow`. But if I write:

```
% Conditional styles
\ifx\colframe\empty\else\tcbset{highlight math style = {colframe = \colframe}}\fi
\ifx\colback\empty\else\tcbset{highlight math style = {colback = \colback}}\fi
\ifx\shadow\empty\else\tcbset{highlight math style = {shadow = {2pt}{-2pt}{0mm}{\shadow}}}\fi
```

It seems to forget the main previously defined `highlight math style` options, and just set the concerned conditional options. How to make this work?

Note: use case:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, onecolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colback = blue]{eqbox}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath{x^2 + 3}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to how I read the `tcolorbox` manual `/tcb/highlight math style={...}` is a shortcut for `/tcb/highlight math/.style={...}`, so this overrides styles, as you say. Therefore I suspect you want `/tcb/highlight math/.append style={...}` instead, and propose to replace the last three lines of your style file by

```
\ifx\colframe\empty\else\tcbset{highlight math/.append style={colframe=\colframe}}\fi
\ifx\colback\empty\else\tcbset{highlight math/.append style={colback=\colback}}\fi
\ifx\shadow\empty\else\tcbset{highlight math/.append style={shadow={2pt}{-2pt}{0mm}{\shadow}}}\fi
```

Comment: Off topic, but [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485325/conditionally-add-options-to-tcolorbox-highlight-math-style#comment1228468_485839) is the 1000th item in my inbox :)) I just discovered that.

Comment: @JouleV Have you [already lost some messages](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7686/121799)? Let's clean up here...

Comment: If inboxes from chat and other sites are counted, I must have got more than 1000. But, well, I have got exactly 999 from TeX.SE (you deleted some comments).

Comment: @JouleV I sometimes really do not see them (in the sense that I do not get the red number on my inbox). In some cases this is a blessing, though. ;-)